Unable to update libcurl - CentoOS 7
on my CentoOS server i cant update libcurl (now 7.29.0 version)
This comand
yum install curl libcurl

Gives me information
Package curl-7.29.0-59.el7_9.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libcurl-7.29.0-59.el7_9.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Is it possible to update curl to higher version?

Even if this is not related to programming: CentOS7 will be EOL within the next ten days.

Follow the guide How to Build and Install Latest cURL Version on CentOS
